# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Collection

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm having a problem while running this code:

```
//DashboardController
```

```
public function getStream()
{
      $user                 = Sentry::getUser();
      $userid               = $user->id;
      $convs                = TBMsg::getUserConversations($userid);
      $getNumOfParticipants = $convs->getNumOfParticipants();
      $participants         = $convs->getAllParticipants();
      $lastMessage          = $convs->getLastMessage();
      $senderId             = $lastMessage->getSender();
      $content              = $lastMessage->getContent();
      $status               = $lastMessage->getStatus();
      $posts                = Post::whereIn('user_id', function($query) {
      $query->select('follow_id')
            ->from('user_follows')
            ->where('user_id', '1');
        })->orWhere('user_id', '1')->get();

      return View::make('stream', array('getNumOfParticipants' => $getNumOfParticipants, 
                                        'participants'         => $participants, 
                                        'lastMessage'          => $lastMessage, 
                                        'senderId'             => $senderId, 
                                        'content'              => $content, 
                                        'status'               => $status
        ))->with('posts', $posts)->with('convs', $convs);
}
```

}

I got this error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Collection::getNumOfParticipants()

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9N3xU.png

Comment: Well `$convs` apparently is a collection of conversation models so you can't call a custom function (probably from the model) on it. What is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: I'm using a package https://github.com/tzookb/tbmsg/blob/master/docs/how_to.md

Comment: Note that in the example they loop over the conversations to get the numbers for every single one using `foreach`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `->get()` with `->first()` as right now you're basically returning an collection of arrays but you need that.

```
 $query->select('follow_id')
        ->from('user_follows')
        ->where('user_id', '1');
    })->orWhere('user_id', '1') // ->get() is removed
    ->first();
```

Comment: I want an array. With your code it throws Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: D:\scripts\phpstream\app\views\stream.blade.php)

Comment: And with get() nothing is printed.

Answer (score 0):

`$convs` is a collection so you can't call a method on it that only exists on a single model. Like the tutorial of the package suggests you have to iterate over the collection to use that function.
[From the how to](https://github.com/tzookb/tbmsg/blob/master/docs/how_to.md):

```
foreach ( $convs as $conv ) {

        $getNumOfParticipants = $conv->getNumOfParticipants();
        $participants = $conv->getAllParticipants();

        /* $lastMessage Tzookb\TBMsg\Entities\Message */
        $lastMessage = $conv->getLastMessage();

        $senderId = $lastMessage->getSender();
        $content = $lastMessage->getContent();
        $status = $lastMessage->getStatus();
    }
```